# What was the "next class starship"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, spaceship

In the Next Generation episode Galaxy's Child the visiting Doctor Leah Brahms comments that one of the engine modifications Geordi made was to be introduced in the next class starship.

> (gazing at the dilithium cradle)
>   LEAH: What happened here? Who did this?
>   LAFORGE: You remember, the crystal's been reoriented to adjust the direction of the lattice structure.
>   [...]
>   LEAH: It's curious. this modification was due to be introduced.
>   LAFORGE: In the next class starship.
>   LEAH: Yes. How did you know?
>   <sub>[Chakoteya.net](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/190.htm)</sub>

Is it known what that next class of starship was, that this change was to be introduced on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Enterpise-**D** was a Galaxy Class starship whereas the Enterprise-**E** was a [Sovereign Class](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Sovereign_class) Starship. There's no canonical description of which ship was the first to have these new engine modifications *as standard*, but we do know that Geordi was the Chief Engineer on the new vessel so it's likely that this change was also brought in here as well.

There's a distinct possibility that Brahms was talking about the [Intrepid Class](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Intrepid_class) starship (of which Voyager was a prime example). It was the very next class that we *see* being rolled out and it certainly contained a number of a vastly improved drive features including variable geometry warp engines and a much more powerful warp core meaning that the ship was capable of *sustained* speeds far in excess of the Galaxy class.

---

For the record, LaForge was the CE on the flagship of the Federation, allegedly the best of the best on the best ship in the fleet. It would be practically criminal if he wasn't fully to speed on modern engineering techniques, as attested by his attending various conferences over the course of the show.

Comment: Was the Sovereign class the next one made? Of the classes I am familiar with I'd have suspected the Defiant or Akira classes maybe, or perhaps some other one.

Comment: But why would this next class be the Sovereign rather than the speedy Intrepid or any other class of ship?

Comment: Booby Trap http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Booby_Trap_%28episode%29 ... and Galaxy's Child http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Galaxy's_Child ... were my 2 top Jordie's episod

Comment: Best of the best of the Best, SIR! With honors! No, seriously, I vote Intrepid. That class came out before the Sovereign, and the Defiant prototype was a special project moreso than a ship of the line model.

Comment: @Omegacron - I put the "allegedly" in there because in real life, the crew of the Enterprise would be immediately replaced by people who aren't idiots.

Comment: @Richard - they DO seem to get themselves in trouble a lot, don't they?

Comment: @Omegacron - This is what happens when you put a toaster in charge of the science division and a toddler at the helm. I'm astounded they made it out of spacedock. Pulaski was the worst though.

Comment: as far as I remember, the Intrepid-class and Sovereign were sister classes, big sister and little sister.

Comment: So Voyager could outrun the Enterprise?

Comment: @maguirenumber6 - Yes, easily. It has a higher top speed, can sustain that speed for longer and has a higher cruising speed

Answer (score 0):

At the moment of the episode the year was 2367, at that time the Intrepid class was in development. The USS Intrepid the class leader was in service by 2370 and the USS Voyager being commissioned in 2371. The Intrepid was designed with various technologies that would be first fielded surpassing advancement of the Galaxy class. Technolgies like biological derived gel suspended computer packs. But namely subspace environmentally friendly warp engines along with restructure dilithium chamber allowing the system to run more efficiently